# How to return firebase data using a class?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a UICollectionView where I populate data using a class. As of now, I am populating it with dummy data, as shown in the code below. I have trying to replace this dummy data with data from my Firebase database.

```
import UIKit

class MrNobody
{
// MARK: - Public API
var title = ""
var description = ""
var numberOfMembers = 0
var numberOfPosts = 0
var featuredImage: UIImage!

init(title: String, description: String, featuredImage: UIImage!)
{
    self.title = title
    self.description = description
    self.featuredImage = featuredImage
    numberOfMembers = 1
    numberOfPosts = 1
}

// MARK: - Private
// dummy data
static func createMrNobody() -> [MrNobody]
{
    return [
        MrNobody(title: "some text" , description: "some text", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "r1")!),
        MrNobody(title: "some text" , description: "some text", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "r1")!),
        MrNobody(title: "some text" , description: "some text", featuredImage: UIImage(named: "r1")!),

    ]
}
}
```

In order to include data, I have included `import Firebase`, identifying my firebase database using `let ref = Firebase(url: "my app url")` and reading data using

```
 ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
print(snapshot.value)
}, withCancelBlock: { error in
print(error.description)
})
```

I am able to read the child data, but I am not being able to use it in the `return` block of the function. Ideally, I would want to use `enumerator = snapshot.childrenCount`, and reiteratively use the `return` function for as many children are there in the node of interest.

Any help/direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey OP, I know your question has already been answered, but I'd encourage you to simply make an initialiser in the `MrNobody` class that takes an `FDataSnapshot`. This is good practice because it allows for code reusability in case you need to use those snapshots in more than one place in your code (perhaps if you listen to the `.ChildAdded` and `.ChildRemoved` event types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The createMrNobody() function call is synchronous and will not behave the same way when you are retrieving data from Firebase.

Firebase is asynchronous in nature so when you ask it for data, you have to wait for that data to be retrieved before processing it. Otherwise the processing code will execute before Firebase has the data ready.

It's different than a SQL query of function call where the entire process is synchronous.

Not sure if this will help, but here's a sample: Suppose we have an array that stores people and we need to populate it from Firebase.

We first define the person class

```
class Person {
        var title: NSString?
        var aDescription: NSString?
    }
```

and the array to store the people

```
var myArray = [Person]()
```

and when you are ready to load them from Firebase, this will do it

```
func loadMyPeople() {

    myUsersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let title = child.value["title"] as! String
            let description = child.value["description"] as! String
            let dude = Person()
            dude.title = title
            dude.aDescription = description
            self.myArray.append(dude)
        }

        //after all your people are loaded in the array, print it's contents
        // you could also reload a tableView here as well.
        for dude in self.myArray {
            print("email: \(dude.title!)  desc: \(dude.description!)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use this recipe to read data from Firebase-database to my TableView. Just for sake of completeness, I had to change `title : NSString, description : NSString ` to `title = "", description = "" ` in the Class file. Otherwise,  I was getting a ` "lldb: Found nil while unwrapping Optional" `error.

Comment: @AtlasShrugged I'm using Swift 2 and am not receiving that error - they should probably be defined at options per my code so perhaps they error is generated elsewhere when one of the properties is nil? Please note that my Person class is a subclass of NSObject, which already has a property 'description' so that's a conflict. I updated my answer and changed the description to aDescription. I'm happy my answer helped!