# Not getting the correct return from function which queries Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using a function to return a value from Firebase, I'm doing this in a class called `DBProvider` and ultimately, what I'm trying to do is retrieve a value (latitude) from Firebase and return it in the function (`getUsersLatitude()`). What I attempted to do was to declare a variable in the function and set it to the value retrieved from Firebase (as seen below):

```
class DBProvider {

static let _instance = DBProvider()

//private init() {}

static var Instance: DBProvider {
    return _instance
}

var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

func getUsersLatitude() -> CLLocationDegrees{
    var latitude = CLLocationDegrees()
    ref.child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("location").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let loc = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
            if let lat = loc["latitude"]{
                latitude = lat as! CLLocationDegrees
                print("LATITUDE - \(latitude)")
            }
        }
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()
    print("OUTSIDE LATITUDE - \(latitude)")
    return latitude
}

}
```

I call this function in another class called `PostViewController`, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil{
        DBProvider.Instance.getUsersLatitude()
    }
}
```

Although, the problem that im having is that it does not return `latitude`, it returns `0.0`. I know this because of the print statements -- `print("LATITUDE - \(latitude)")`, which is the one inside ref..., comes out with the correct latitude, `55.633348`.

Whereas, `print("OUTSIDE LATITUDE - \(latitude)")`, which is the one outside ref..., does not come out with the correct latitude, `0.0`.

When if filter for the word "LATITUDE" in the debugger, this is the output I get:

[image: The image of my debugger output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `observeSingleEvent` works asynchronously. You need a completion block for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: Thank you but how could i adapt that and use it in my case?

Comment: The linked question contains a few examples. The class is different but the callback pattern is always the same.

Comment: This isn't how Firebase works. It is not designed to be called as a function that returns a value. Observing a node returns the requested data within a closure, and the data is not valid until the closure executes. i.e. your function will return before the data can be retrieved from Firebase... code is faster than the internet. So in your case, the latitude variable will be returned before it's populated in the closure. See [How to return firebase data using a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360927/how-to-return-firebase-data-using-a-class/36364566#36364566)

Comment: Solved it, cheers for your help everyone!